# Nested loop OpenMP Parallellizing, private or public index?

Tags: c++, c, for-loop, parallel-processing, openmp

Imagine you have a nested loop for in a parallel region, something like:

```
#pragma omp parallel
{
     for (int i = 0, ...) {
          for (int j = 0, ...) { }}}
```

or

```
#pragma omp parallel
{
     for (int i = 0, ...) {
          for (int j = i, ...) { }}}
```

If we use #pragma omp for, automatically the i index becomes private. But...  do we need to **set the j index** to private or public? What is the effect?

```
#pragma omp parallel
{
     #pragma omp for shared(j)
     for (int i = 0, ...) {
           for (int j = 0, ...) { }}}
```

or

```
#pragma omp parallel
{
     #pragma omp for private(j)
     for (int i = 0, ...) {
          for (int j = 0, ...) { }}}
```

Thanks in advance!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Private j has no effect as j is private by defaults(since it is scoped within the i for loop so when a new thread is created j is specific to that thread

```
#pragma omp parallel for private(j)
for (int i = 0, ...) {
     for (int j = 0, ...) { }}
```

If you use `shared j` it should have no effect as stated above since the scope of j is local to each instance of i, if you expand the scope of j to global, you will encounter a race codition

Comment: So with i private and j shared I will have race condition?

Comment: If j has global scope yes , if j is locally declared no race condition will occur

Comment: @alienflow You **cannot** set `j` to shared because it is undefined at the scope of the parallel region. Thus no race condition but a compiler error (for any sane compiler).

Answer (score 3):

Everything declarded inside the parallel region is automatically private. That is (presumably) the behavior you want: Each iteration of `i` should loop through all `j`, the `j` loops are all independent (thus private, not public). However, you are actually lacking the important `parallel` part: If you don't write

`#pragma omp parallel for`

but only

`#pragma omp for`

then you won't get anything happening in parallel (unless you first created a parallel region with `#pragma omp parallel` in an enclosing scope)!

Comment: What? This is for parallelizing for loops !! https://www.ibm.com/support/knowledgecenter/SSGH2K_11.1.0/com.ibm.xlc111.aix.doc/compiler_ref/prag_omp_for.html

Comment: For a for loop you can use either pragma omp parallel {} or pragma omp for without {} !!

Comment: `#pragma omp for` can be used as well, just it needs to be encapsulated by `#pragma omp parallel` region. From the linked page you mentioned: _"The `omp for` directive instructs the compiler to **distribute loop iterations within the team of threads that encounters this work-sharing construct**."_. That _team of threads_ is created by `parallel` OpenMP construct.

Comment: @alienflow It is. But it doesn't do anything unless you are in a parallel region.

Comment: @DanielLangr I have made that point more explicit in an edit, thanks.